# nginx unit + django + docker - wsgi.py cannot import module

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx

Currently containerizing a legacy Django project, and running into an odd error.

When pushing the config file to the running server, it fails to apply, and on inspecting the log, I get the following:

```
2023/12/06 21:36:02 [info] 39#39 discovery started
2023/12/06 21:36:02 [notice] 39#39 module: python 3.11.2 "/usr/lib/unit/modules/python3.11.unit.so"
2023/12/06 21:36:02 [info] 1#1 controller started
2023/12/06 21:36:02 [notice] 1#1 process 39 exited with code 0
2023/12/06 21:36:02 [info] 41#41 router started
2023/12/06 21:36:02 [info] 41#41 OpenSSL 3.0.11 19 Sep 2023, 300000b0
2023/12/06 21:40:22 [info] 49#49 "myapp" prototype started
2023/12/06 21:40:22 [info] 50#50 "myapp" application started
2023/12/06 21:40:22 [alert] 50#50 Python failed to import module "myapp.wsgi"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/myapp/wsgi.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application  # noqa: E402
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
2023/12/06 21:40:22 [notice] 49#49 app process 50 exited with code 1
2023/12/06 21:40:22 [warn] 41#41 failed to start application "myapp"
2023/12/06 21:40:22 [alert] 41#41 failed to apply new conf
2023/12/06 21:40:22 [notice] 1#1 process 49 exited with code 0
```

My config file is as follows:

```
{
    "applications": {
        "myapp": {
            "type": "python 3.11",
            "module": "myapp.wsgi",
            "processes": 150,
            "environment": {
                "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE": "myapp.settings.production",
            }
        }
    },

    "listeners": {
        "0.0.0.0:8000": {
            "pass": "applications/myapp"
        }
    }
}
```

Swapping out unit for Gunicorn results in the expected behavior, as well as running the Django development server.

I did notice the version of Python 3 the nginx-unit module is using slightly differs from the one i have installed in the container(Python 3.11.2 vs Python 3.11.7), but don't see why this would cause this specific issue.

Is nginx-unit having problems locating my Python paths?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your container does not have django installed? Did you create an environment, install django to it and then activate it? It is not sufficient to `pip install uwsgi`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue by pulling from the official `unit:python3.11` image instead of pulling from the regular `python 3.11` image I had been previous and manually installing unit.